# What does the man mean by saying this statement?

Tags: meaning, reading-comprehension

I read [this NYP article](https://nypost.com/2014/12/29/the-record-breaking-roadster-with-3-million-miles/amp/) about a Volvo car breaking Guinness word record. However, at the end of the article the man said this sentence which I don’t understand:

> “I don’t see my ex-wife or my kids. I can’t say if that is because of the driving,” he said.

Does he mean he loves the car more than his family?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little joke. He's saying he drives so much, he might have driven his family away with it. It's possible, of course, that that is actually the case, but people tend to make jokes like that about how their passions alienate them from their relatives.